# When to use the phrase " correct me if I am wrong "

Tags: phrase-usage

I recently found out the phrase "correct me if I am wrong" I searched it on internet and I understood it's meaning but I am little confused in its usage . my question is when should one use this phrase .In what situation and with what intention it is usually said.

Answer (score 5):

Commonly it is used when:

1. You are stating a 'fact' (usually an opinion or a truth that you know/believe in), and you think the listener(s) or the audience or the person/people you are talking to probably have something else to say (or there might be other possible 'facts'/opinions.)

> e.g. "Correct me if I'm wrong. There are 4 cats in the attic."

2. When you are re-stating the recent message of another person, to confirm if you remember correctly what was said.

> e.g. "Correct me if I'm wrong, doctor. So, I need to take this medicine twice a day for two weeks?"

There might be other usage(s), will update this answer if something comes up (or let's wait for other answers)

Answer (score 2):

It can also be used sarcastically:

> *Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I'm concerned the capital of Germany is still Berlin.*

Comment: I'm not from Germany, nor have a substantial knowledge of its history. May I request for context and explanation regarding this answer's example? (I'm just curious re: sarcasm and capital. Thanks.)

Comment: It is abbreviated as CMIIW and commonly used here.

Comment: @shin - Simon's answer really has little to do with Germany and world capitals; it's saying that when we use the phrase in front of an undisputable fact, it's often interpreted sarcastically. In other words, if I said, "Correct me if I'm wrong, but, last I checked, ELL is not in beta anymore," then I'm not expecting anyone to correct me. Instead, I am using CMIIW for emphasis, to make it more plain that I'm stating a fact, not an opinion. In other words, "Correct me if I'm wrong" can be a way of (sarcastically) saying, "There's no sense in disputing what I'm about to say..."

Comment: @J.R., thank you for this explanation. It's new to me. We never really stop learning here. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm non-native but whereever I hear this phrase **"Correct me of I'm wrong"** it mostly means **"Tell me if something that I am saying is incorrect or not true"**.

- Excuse me, correct me if I'm wrong but this book belongs to Michael and not Lily.

In some cases it means **"I know what I'm telling you (I am sure that it should be true)"**

- Mom, correct me if I'm wrong but Canada is larger than USA.